# Safari 8 label + checkbox hover flicker, how to prevent?

Tags: html, css, safari

On the first :hover in Safari 8 checkboxes and radio buttons which are checked will flicker as if it is being clicked. Sample code:

```
<div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked> Hover me in Safari 8</label>
</div>

<style>
div {
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 1em;
}
label {
    line-height: 2em;
    display: block;
}
label:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

I have also created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NiklasBr/99trnpab/1/), but keep in mind that this only happens on the first hover event and not on subsequent ones. You need to re-run the code to trigger it again.

Does anyone know where this behaviour stems from and how to prevent it? Neither Chrome nor Firefox exhibits this flicker.

**Update**

I reported this to Apple at bugreporter.apple.com and they closed my issue (radar 21101864) with the status *Duplicate of 17781269 (Open)*.

Comment: @ketan this is what it looks like for me: https://imgflip.com/gif/m04p4

Comment: Which version of safari you are using?

Comment: Version 8.0.6 (10600.6.3)

Comment: I am using old(5.1.7) still didn't getting that issue.

Comment: Yeah, I know that it does not happen in older versions of Safari. I have made it clear now by editing that this is only happening in Safari 8 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Applying `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to the input element worked for me (dirty though, I know).